# Change Fragment dynamically

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two tabs according to the number of category items (Mutton, Sea food) created dynamically.

In MenumainActivity I'm able to store Mutton items in ArrayList named listitemsAll and Sea food items in ArrayList named listitemsAll1 by doing this if (cat == 1)....

MenumainActivity:

```
public void onSuccess(String response) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {        9           

    JSONObject hotels = obj.getJSONObject("Menu");
    JSONArray items = hotels.getJSONArray("Items");
    for (int j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject hotel = items.getJSONObject(j);
                        categoryname = hotel.getString("name");
                        categoryid = hotel.getString("id");
                        hotelmenu = hotel.getJSONArray(categoryname);
                        listitems = new ArrayList<Menuclass>();
                        listitems1 = new ArrayList<Menuclass>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < hotelmenu.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject menuitems = hotelmenu.getJSONObject(i);
                            itemname = menuitems.getString("name");
                            itemsprice = menuitems.getString("price");
                            itemtype = menuitems.getString("veg");
                            final int itemtypeint = Integer.parseInt(itemtype);
                            cat = Integer.parseInt(categoryid);

                            if (cat == 1) {
                                if (itemtypeint == 0) {

                                    listitems.add(new Menuclass(itemname, itemsprice, R.drawable.nonveg));
                                }

                                else {
                                    listitems.add(new Menuclass(itemname, itemsprice, R.drawable.vegicon));
                                }
            else if (cat == 2) {
                                if (itemtypeint == 0) {

                                    listitems1.add(new Menuclass(itemname, itemsprice, R.drawable.nonveg));
                                }

                                else {
                                    listitems1.add(new Menuclass(itemname, itemsprice, R.drawable.vegicon));
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        listitemsAll.addAll(listitems);
                        listitemsAll.addAll(listitems1);
                        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText((categoryname)));
                        ViewPagerAdapter1 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager(),items);
                        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new
```

Comment: Please share the code for MenuViewAdapter

Comment: Shared Menuview Adapter

Comment: Is this JSON being created from a server you dont have access to? I would recommend changing the array of json containing `Mutton,Sea Food..etc` to `dishes`. and then This JSON can be easily converted to a Java Class Object using GSON converter. http://pastebin.com/UgLDb3NW . I can share the code for the rest once you confirm if JSON can be changed

Comment: Changed the JSON (Mutton, Sea Food...) to Dishes

Answer (score 0):

Once you have changed the JSON to

```
{
"Menu": {
"Items": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "kd_sub1_mnu",
    "name": "Mutton",
    "status": "1",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "hot1_sub1_mut",
        "name": "Mutton Peper Fry",
        "price": "100",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "hot1_sub2_mut",
        "name": "Mutton Curry",
        "price": "100",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "hot1_sub3_mut",
        "name": "Mutton Rogan Josh",
        "price": "100",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "code": "hot1_sub4_mut",
        "name": "Mutton Mohalai",
        "price": "100",
        "veg": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "kd_sub2_mnu",
    "name": "Sea Food",
    "status": "1",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "hot1_sub1_sf",
        "name": "Fish Fry",
        "price": "150",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "hot1_sub2_sf",
        "name": "Chilly Fish",
        "price": "250",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "hot1_sub3_sf",
        "name": "Finger Fish",
        "price": "350",
        "veg": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "kd_sub3_mnu",
    "name": "Noodels",
    "status": "1",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "hot1_sub1_nd",
        "name": "Chicken Noodels",
        "price": "70",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "hot1_sub3_nd",
        "name": "Veg Noodles",
        "price": "55",
        "veg": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "code": "kd_sub4_mnu",
    "name": "Egg",
    "status": "1",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "hot1_sub1_egg",
        "name": "Scrambled Egg",
        "price": "20",
        "veg": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "code": "kd_sub5_mnu",
    "name": "Vegetarian Dishes",
    "status": "1",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "hot1_sub1_veg",
        "name": "Veg./ Gobi Man.Dry",
        "price": "60",
        "veg": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "hot1_sub2_veg",
        "name": "Panner Manchoorian Dry",
        "price": "60",
        "veg": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "code": "kd_sub6_mnu",
    "name": "Tandoor",
    "status": "1",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "hot1_sub1_ta",
        "name": "Naan",
        "price": "15",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "hot1_sub2_ta",
        "name": "Butter naan",
        "price": "20",
        "veg": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "hot1_sub3_ta",
        "name": "Kulcha",
        "price": "15",
        "veg": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
},
 "status": "true"
}
```

You can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and paste your JSON object to create 4 Java classes as

```
public class Menuclass {

@SerializedName("Menu")
@Expose
private Menu menu;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

public Menu getMenu() {
return menu;
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
this.menu = menu;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

}

public class Dish {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private String price;
@SerializedName("veg")
@Expose
private String veg;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
this.price = price;
}

public String getVeg() {
return veg;
}

public void setVeg(String veg) {
this.veg = veg;
}

}


public class Item {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("dishes")
@Expose
private List<Dish> dishes = null;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public List<Dish> getDishes() {
return dishes;
}

public void setDishes(List<Dish> dishes) {
this.dishes = dishes;
}

}

public class Menu {

@SerializedName("Items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = null;

public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
this.items = items;
}

}
```

You may change the name of the classes if you want.

Now just change your `onSuccess()` method as follows:

```
Menuclass menuClassObject;
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    menuClassObject = (new Gson()).fromJson(response,Menuclass.class);
}
```

Now the `menuClassObject` contains the response JSON converted to the class object.

MenuFragment's OnCreateView :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);
    ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.Listview1);
    position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);


    MenuViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new MenuViewAdapter(getActivity(), menuClassObject,position);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

Change your MenuViewAdapter :

```
public class MenuViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater layoutinflater;
private Menuclass menuClass;
private ArrayList<Dish> listStorage;
private Context context;
private int pagerPosition;

public MenuViewAdapter(Context context, Menuclass customMenuClass,int position) {
    this.context = context;
    layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    menuClass = customMenuClass;
    pagerPosition = position;
    listStorage = new ArrayList<>();
    listStorage = menuClass.getMenu().getItems().get(position).getDishes();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listStorage.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 Dish dish = listStorage.get(position);
 //Now Dish class has methods you need. Customize your view here based on the Dish.

 }
```

Comment: Worked well successfully